# How to use REGEXREPLACE in Google Sheets for multiple strings

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column with such as `Alpha :15s V1` .`Beta :15s V2` .`Delta :06s V3`. I am trying to use `regexreplace` but it won't remove the `V` from the string. Here is the formula which I have used so far.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(T2, "[V]|[V1]-|[V2]|[V3]","")
```

How do I get this to work where I get the output just as `Alpha :15s`

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, you want to remove `V1`, `V2` and `V3` from the end of your text, for which you should use `V[123]` regex instead of `[V]|[V1]-|[V2]|[V3]` and to be further precise, use `\s*V\d*$` regex.

[image]

Here `\s*` matches any whitespace then matches `V` and then matches one or more digits and finally `$` matches end of line.

And the reason why it didn't work for you is, when you place characters in square brackets, it is called a character class and match any one character inside square bracket. Hence `[V1]` will match either `V` or `1` and replace that with empty string which is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this fx:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.*) V")))
```

[image: 0]

which translates as: extract everything `(.*)` before space followed by V `(.*) V`

Comment: What if there is no pattern at all to the strings that you want to remove (no pattern in their character count, position in the parent string, etc..) and you want to target them specifically listing them out? 

So in the above example, what if you wanted to omit just the words "Alpha" and ":06s"?

Comment: @ShianHan then it would be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "Alpha|:06s", )))`